# How do I share Javascript files between projects in VS2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

I cannot find a way to share javascript files between projects in VS2015.  In VS2013, I used to be able to link files from another project and then run a build script to copy the files over so that they would be local to the project when debugging.  This was great for my development team, because it made it convenient to be able to see the linked file on the current project and actually be working on the file in the shared project.

I tried adding a Shared Project in VS2015 and adding my javascript files there, but I cannot see how I can link them or make them accessible to the current project.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet may be to create an internal CDN and host the files there. The developers can reference the script files from the internal CDN. I don't believe it's terribly difficult to configure a CDN in IIS.

Comment: im confused by what you mean... if you could do it in 2013 then you can defo do it in 2015... so just do the something..

Comment: Seabizkit - The "Add as Link" feature is missing out of VS2015.  We had a project that contained all our shared JS files and if we wanted to reuse them, we would add them as a link from the shared project.

Comment: Getting closer, but I do not understand the proposal on how to include files from another project into the project.json file.  Link: [Article describing the problem](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/147)

Comment: Could be a possible solution.  Link:  [Serving Static Files](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#serving-static-files)

Comment: Hey @RonB I am revisiting this to see if you have made any progress. I was able to find the "Add as Link" option in my VS 2015 "Add Existing Item" menu.

Comment: No, I am just going to have to find a different way.  I found that the Add as Link option is not available on MVC6 projects.